# Pentaho MS-SQL set IDENTITY_INSERT a00 ON for table output

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

PDI 9.0

Simple job 
MS SQL connection
Table input -> tableouput

tableouput table :
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[a00](
    [ProductID] [int]  NOT NULL **[IDENTITY(1,1)][1]**
   ..

I need to write IDENTITY explicitly 
in SSMS I run 
set IDENTITY_INSERT a00 ON
and doing insert ok.

In pentaho I got error
Table output.0 - Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'a00' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

trying to run in SQl : set IDENTITY_INSERT a00 ON
Before
SQL -> table input -> table output
but same error

Seems  set IDENTITY_INSERT a00 ON runs in DIFFerent SESSION 
then table output

How can I run set IDENTITY_INSERT a00 ON in same session 
or point out  to use it ;

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho tries to do everything in parallel while on the same Transformation. So you need to create a job and do it sequentialy 
1st - SQL script "SET IDENTITY_INSERT a00 ON"
2nd - Your transformation with the table output
3th - SQL script "SET IDENTITY_INSERT a00 OFF"

Example:

[image: JOB]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi 
Idea was good but do Not work out

set IDENTITY_INSERT a00 ON ;
Same  error
Seems it runs in OTHER session 

Question does this work at your PC ?

Answer (score 0):

I checked using profiler 
SQL run in one session
transformation in another
here is problem 
do not know how to resolev it

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding an extra option to my database connection.
Under "Advanced" in the database connection, enter a SQL statement that will be executed right after connecting to the database.

My statement (MSSQL) looks like

```
set identity_insert [dbname].[schemaname].[tablename] on;
```

Your `tablename` could also be set with a variable.